# VBA to put code programmatically in sheet-level macro

Tags: excel, vba

I was trying to use `Workbook_SheetFollowHyperlink()` to trigger a macro if the user clicks the hyperlink.

However, this `Workbook_SheetFollowHyperlink` macro is to be inserted on a sheet-level, not on the module level.

Is there any way that I can programmatically add this `Workbook_SheetFollowHyperlink` macro to every sheet? The reason is, I create these sheets on the fly using VBA, and the number of sheets and their names are not known in advance beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Workbook_SheetFollowHyperlink` is defined in the *ThisWorkbook* class module.  (At *Worksheet* level, it's `Worksheet_FollowHyperlink`)

So, you already have what you need: an Event that responds to following a Hyperlink on *any* sheet in the workbook.

Comment: Thanks. But is there a way that I could add codes programatically to the ThisWorkbook object?

Comment: You can modify the VBA at run time (using `Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3` in Tools>References.)